# Send commands from touchscreen application to a PC

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, remote-control, touchscreen

I am trying to figure out a way in which I can send commands initiated on a touchscreen application I created for a tablet, to a host PC. Right now, the touchscreen app is a simple button grid, each button navigates to a website...but it navigates to a website on the tablet...not the host PC. Is there a way, or software that already exists, that will allow me to specify on the tablet to route the commands to a PC and for the PC to receive the command and open the websites?

Most of what I have found is a remote desktop application. The problem is that I do not want to run the application on the target PC. I want the touchscreen to control the target without having any of the applications on the target PC. Tablets will either be iPad or Samsung. At the moment I am testing with another laptop w/ touchscreen. Target is a company computer, so ability to modify is extremely limited (no admin rights). Any thoughts or ideas on how I can get the target to accept incoming commands?

Comment: I was thinking a good start would be to configure the app to use maybe a [PSexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx) to send your command to your host pc on your network. Just and Idea. I have no Idea what software or tablet you are using to give you better information.

Comment: Yes, sry about the lack of info. Currently using Lenovo Yoga 700 laptop to work on app. WIN 10 OS. Target PC is Lenovo desktop, running WIN7.

Comment: I have used OSCulator on a mac for routing control commands to DAW, and ideally there would be something similar in terms of being able to receive and specify how the commands are interpreted, but I have not been able to find anything similar. I will look into PSexec and see if it might do the trick.